# Converting SVG to drawing commands

Tags: geometry, functions

Is there anyway I could convert SVG Cubic Bezier path to simple shapes?
I need this so that I can write a computer utility that converts a given SVG path to drawing commands.  For example:
Input is: M177.627,456.011 C 178.641,455.531 179.533,455.063 180.317,454.639
Output will be: drawCircle(177.627, 456.011, 45);
(signature here is: drawCircle(Xcentre, Ycentre, r);)

(Note that the above SVG path does not give a circle this is purely for illustration what I am after).

Simple shapes here are -

- lines
- circles
- arcs
- triangles
- polygons
- rectangles

Many Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: To make this clear, I was hoping for a math equation that I can implement on a computer. Not the actual computer code

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the Bézier curve by a string of circular arcs. One easy approximation technique is using [biarc curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biarc) (pairs of smoothly connected circular arcs).

If you googled the term “biarc approximation” or search this site, you’ll find lots of good material.

C++ code [here](https://www.ryanjuckett.com/biarc-interpolation/).

Some graphics subsystems support Bézier curves directly, so you don’t need to do any conversion in order to draw them. Postscript and Windows Metafiles, for example.